# Grunt Serve not working: "Cannot find module 'accepts'"

Tags: node.js

Currently trying to launch a webpage through Grunt Serve and it is constantly being aborted due to this error.

```
"Warning: Cannot find module 'accepts' Use --force to continue.
```

Any idea why exactly this is happening? If I use --force, it means livereload does not work and the webpage does not open on the localhost, basically resulting in it not working.

Any answers on how to solve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Woops, appears I have solved it myself.

```
npm install accepts
```

This seemed to have worked, followed with installing 'batch' soon after it.
It feels like my nom hadn't install all the dependencies was required. I'll look into this.

Keeping this up for anyone who might have a similar problem.